# NSNetServices in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, networking

I am developing an Wireless app and my question looks like this:
1)Is it possible to send data back and fourth between devices using NSNetServices, like Peer-to-Peer, Bonjour example from apple works only with on a local network, it means that if there is no Router available around the NSNetBrowser will not be will not be able to find any devices from the local network ... how to make a peer-to-peer exchange without any extern routers, and is its possible how, please help, maybe someone knows, some sample projects or something!!! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Peer to peer services function by having a tracker, which knows the ip addresses of the people wishing to share files. Otherwise the two ends do not have any way of knowing about each other. Bonjour can, as you say, only know about things on the local network (if it could know about the whole internet, things would rapidly get out of hand). When you connect to a website, its ip address is worked out from its URL, devices don't have that, so you can't just connect the two of them. If your question is then how do I implement a bit-torrent client, it's an interesting one and I don't have an answer off the top of my head. You could always explore the code of existing open source efforts like [transmission](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser).